# Benefits of Stagemonitor over JMX monitoring

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, elastic-stack, stagemonitor

How does [Stagemonitor](http://www.stagemonitor.org/) compare over simple JMX metrics?

Unlike java-native JMX MBeans, Stagemonitor includes an agent that sits in your Java application, sending metrics and request traces at the central database, which can be Elasticsearch.

Since both ways can serve as input for an ELK Monitoring Stack (JMX see this blog [post](https://deors.wordpress.com/2017/02/21/build-your-own-application-performance-monitoring-apm-solution-with-elk-and-jmx-part-1/)) what are the benefits of Stagemonitor?

Comment: Ads are getting smarter...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the metrics stagemonitor collects are not available via JMX. For example, response time statistics grouped by the endpoint of your application.

Also, stagemonitor is much more than just metrics. It is also a profiler, you can use to see which methods caused a request to be slow. Further more, it can (soon) do distributed tracing which helps you to analyze and debug latency problems in a microservice environment by correlating related requests. It also offers you a Kibana dashboard you can use to drill into the requests your application serves to find out about causes of errors or latency. Another use case is lightweight web analytics to identify which devices and operating systems your customers use to access your site.